# Mysql: how to find if column value in a list of strings

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, subquery, sql-like

Mysql: how to find if column value in a list contains many strings.
Expl: t.name=‘test’

```
Select * 
from table t 
where ( t.name Like [‘test tuto1’, ‘test tuto2’, ‘test tuto3’, ‘teeeest’....]
```

I have to get * with t.name contains the first 3 exemples result

Answer (score 2):

There are several option for this :

1) build a series of `OR`ed expressions like :

```
SELECT t.* from mytable t WHERE t.name LIKE '%val1%' or t.name LIKE '%val2%'...
```

2) Use `find_in_set` : probably more efficient than combined `LIKE`s

```
SELECT t.* from mytable t WHERE find_in_set(t.name, 'val1,val2,...')
```

3) Use a regexp : same order of speed as `find_in_set`

```
SELECT t.* from mytable t WHERE t.name REGEXP 'val1|val2|...';
```

4) If you have a very large list of values, your query will slow down and you would eventually hit the max size of a varchar in the expression that represents the list. I would recommend stuffing them in a database table and the use a `WHERE EXIST` condition with a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from mylist where t.name like CONCAT('%', l.val '%'))
```

5) with MySQL 8.0, the list table can be emulated [with a CTE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/) :

```
WITH mylist AS (
    SELECT '%val1%' UNION SELECT '%val2%' UNION ...)
)
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from mylist where t.name like CONCAT('%', l.val '%'))
```

Comment: Good response.  Additional note: [What's a "CTE"?](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/)

Comment: @paulsm4 : Thanks for the positive comment ! Link added to my response.

Comment: Thanks! The `REGEXP` example just saved me some time =)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this post. What about:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.name IN ('name1,name2,name3,name4,...')
```

I am sure the FIND_IN_SET and REGEX solutions are way more performant but I didn't want to let the IN operator unmentioned.

Comment: Using `IN` will match if `t.name` = 'nam` (for example), so probably not what you want in this case.